# Route Me: Location & Screen Position

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, dictionary, route-me

I am drawing a bunch of Markers on my Map View.
The information about the position of all objects (latitude and longitude) is stored in an Array.
To optimize performance i don't want to draw **ALL** Markers. I only want to alloc Markers in the area i am seeing at the moment. But the only information i get from the Route Me API about position/screen is:

```
center.latitude;
center.longitude;
```

But this value is only returning the center of my whole map and i want to see the center position (lat and long) of the actual view. I am also able to get the GPS position, but not the center position of the screen. Do you think there is an easy way to get this information?

This is a part of my implementation:

```
UIImage* object = [UIImage imageNamed:@"object.png"];
CLLocationCoordinate2D buoyLocation;   
    NSString* templatString;
    NSString* templongString;

   for (int i =0; i<(myArray.count); i=i+2)

            {

            templongString = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
            templatString = [myarray objectAtIndex:i+1];

            objectLocation.latitude  = [templatString floatValue];
            objectLocation.longitude  = [templongString floatValue];


            myMarker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:object anchorPoint:CGPointMake(xspec, yspec)]; //0.5 1.0            
            [markerManager1 addMarker:myMarker AtLatLong:objectLocation];


         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at latitudeLongitudeBoundingBoxForScreen in [RMMapContents](http://www.mobilegeographics.com/dev/routeme/interface_r_m_map_contents.html).

Ciao!

-- Randy